# Get value of promise returned by a function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am working on a ReactJs project.

I have a function that returns a promise with the user data {Promise < user >}.
This function is called using `window.myAuth.isUserLoggedIn()` in the .tsx file.

The response can be seen in the console-
[image]

I want to store the value returned by this promise in some local variable of the tsx file.

How can i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

if you use functional component then you can use `useState`

```
// This is declaration
const [loginInfo, setLoginInfo] = useState({});
// in .then() you can set the loginInfo
setLoginInfo(response.data);
```

If you use class component then you can use `state` object

```
// in constructor
this.state = {
   loginInfo = {}
}
// in .then() you can set the loginInfo
this.state({loginInfo: response.data});
```